# Problema com o MediaSource

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema ao usar o MediaSource do Javascript, eu tenho um video que esta dividido em varias arquivos de 10 segundos e depois o navegador do utilizador renderiza o video e mostra o video todo por inteiro mas por algum motivo isso não esta a acontecer, ele simplesmente pega no ultimo pedaço do video e da play. Podem testar este problema em http://2.81.244.98:8080/ProgressVideo Com um arquivo de audio em um outro projecto também com arquivos divididos tudo funciona ok: http://2.81.244.98:8080/ProgressAudio

Uma outra pergunta é recomendavel usar .webm para este tipo de sistema?

Codigo JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  var baseUrl = 'http://2.81.244.98:8080/ProgressVideo/fn/';
  var initUrl = baseUrl + 'out000.webm';
  var templateUrl = baseUrl + 'out00$Number$.webm';
  var sourceBuffer;
  var index = 1;
  var numberOfChunks = 82;
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  if (!window.MediaSource) {
    console.error('No Media Source API available');
    return;
  }
  var ms = new MediaSource();
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ms);
  ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', onMediaSourceOpen);
  function onMediaSourceOpen() {
    sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', nextSegment);
    GET(initUrl, appendToBuffer);
  }
  function nextSegment() {
    if(index >= 10){
      templateUrl = baseUrl + 'out0$Number$.webm';
    }
    var url = templateUrl.replace('$Number$', index);
    GET(url, appendToBuffer);
    index++;
    if (index > numberOfChunks) {
      sourceBuffer.removeEventListener('updateend', nextSegment);
    }
  }
  function appendToBuffer(videoChunk) {
    if (videoChunk) {
      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(videoChunk));
    }
  }
  function GET(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (xhr.status != 200) {
        console.warn('Unexpected status code ' + xhr.status + ' for ' + url);
        return false;
      }
      callback(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.send();
  }
})();
```